# FireBase - Configuration for Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I want to connect my app (written in Kotlin) with Firebase Cloud Messaging but I cannot get it to receive messages from firebase...

Code:

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="kubacki.com.expiryassistant">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessaging"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Message Receiver class:

```
package kubacki.com.expiryassistant

import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage

class MyFirebaseMessaging : FirebaseMessagingService() {

private val TAG = "FIREBASE"

override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage?) {
    super.onMessageReceived(p0)

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + p0?.from)
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + p0?.notification)
}

override fun onNewToken(p0: String?) {
    super.onNewToken(p0)

    Log.d(TAG, p0)
}

}
```

build.grade (Project)

```
buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // FIREBASE
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kubacki.com.expiryassistant"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'

    // ButterKnife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    // RxJava
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.16"

    // RxAndroid
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'

    // FIREBASE
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In the console I can see that Firebase in initalized successfully but I cannot see any messages received after sending them via console.

I might have forgotten about some steps of configuration but I have already went through all tutorials and I believe that my code should work.

Thank you for all help on this case.

Comment: Which Android version are you testing on? If it's 8.0 or later, have you created a notifiction channel?

Comment: Android 7.0 Nougat

Answer (score 0):

give the internet permission to your app in Android Manifest.
I think it will help you

Add this code line for enable internet connection

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).